# JNI -- It is possible to pass complex type as native method parameters?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

The most of examples I have seen using JNI pass parameters of  primary type  to native methods that can be easily mapped according to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html)

My  question is about complex type for example  java object  it is possible to pass it as a native method parameter ? and How use it in the c++ side ?

Comment: You already know it: Every native method implementation is passed a `jclass` and, if not static, a `jobject`. Explicit parameters in native methods work the same way.

Comment: Passing a Mat object to native code as a "long" using the java Mat getNativeObjAddr() method : read that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193039/how-to-pass-a-arraylistmat-from-java-to-native-sidendk-in-opencv-for-android

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is posible to access objects. The [JNI spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html) describes the principles quite well in chapters

- Referencing Java Objects
- Accessing Fields and Methods

The basic excerpt is this:

JNI does **not** give you a C++ counterpart for your classes. **Every** object type is passed to the C code as an opaque `jobject` (or 'jstring' or 'jarray' and a few more).

JNI provides you with utilities which extract other meta informations from these `jobject`s like ids for fields and methods. `GetIntField` is one of those utility methods.

When you have a field ID you can use methods like `SetIntField` to set the value of the field or retrieve it using either `SetIntField` or `GetIntField`.

This is only a rough outline of course.

Comment: I try to pass an opencv type which is `Mat` like this `public void native method ( Mat mat) ` but when I run javah command to generate the header file , I get the error `cannot find Mat `

Comment: @nawara Did you look into the linked spec?

Comment: yes  I understand this  , may be in my case I should look for a method that copy the value of my variable of type `Mat` passed as paramter of the native methods to be used by the C++ function 
`Mat` is primary a C++ type

Comment: @nawara: Do you say, that `Mat` is not a Java type but a C++ type? If so then I don't understand your original question because that is about giving Java objects as argument to JNI methods.

Comment: `Mat` is originally a C++ type referred to OpenCV Library which now supports desktop JAVA so I can use variable of `Mat`  type in java programm after adding `1) opencv jar ` and `2) opencv native library (.so) ` and I would to pass a parameter of `Mat`type to the native method in java side and used it in the C++ side

Comment: @nawara This has nothing to do with JNI. If OpenVC provides a Java type `Mat` and a C++ type `Mat` then they also have provided quite a bunch of glue code between these two worlds. And only they know how this glue works. So please ask a new question stating OpenVC and your requirements right from the start.