# Pass Array of Mat to NDK

Tags: java, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I followed same steps of taking native address in array and passed to NDK.[Arraylist pass java to ndk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193039/how-to-pass-a-arraylistmat-from-java-to-native-sidendk-in-opencv-for-android)
And in the native side i done as given below,

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_app_android_flowerhgram_1woutcondition_TemplateMatch_MatchTemplate
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass, jlong addrProcessed, jlongArray  templates, jobject out){

   Mat& mProcesseed = *(Mat *)addrProcessed;
   vector <Mat> trainimgs;

   jint retVal=0;
   int num=0,temp=0;

      jclass alCls = env->FindClass("org/opencv/core/Mat");
      jmethodID jMatCons = env->GetMethodID(alCls,"<init>","()V");
      jmethodID alGetId  = env->GetMethodID(alCls, "getNativeObjAddr", "()J");
      jmethodID sizeMethodID = env->GetMethodID(alCls, "size", "()I");

      jlong *traindata = env->GetLongArrayElements(templates,0);

      int intValue = *(int*) sizeMethodID;

    for(int k=0;k < intValue ; k++)
    {
        Mat & newimage=*(Mat*)traindata[k];
        trainimgs.push_back(newimage);
    }
      env->ReleaseLongArrayElements(templates,traindata,0);
   return retVal;
   }
```

For this i am not facing any build error, but while compiling i getting error in size 
`Pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;.size()I`".

please guide me for this or any other solution will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with org.opencv.core.Mat class, but isn't size returning Size (org.opencv.core.Size) instead of integer?

Comment: I tried with org.opencv.core.Size class also, same error is repeating. And for your reference i passed address of array.length to NDK from java.

Comment: What I am referring here is this line: env->GetMethodID(alCls, "size", "()I"); Shouldn't it read: env->GetMethodID(alCls, "size", "()Lorg/opencv/core/Size;");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long study, i found the solution for this question. Hope this may useful for others

To get length of array the below line can be used,

```
jsize a_len = env->GetArrayLength(templates);
```

And `a_len` can be used in for loop

This solved my problem for my above question.